# Fix .htaccess .mp4 hotlink protection for mobile

Tags: html, ios, apache, .htaccess, mobile

I made an .htaccess to protect against .mp4 stream hotlinker. So far it work fine on PC and all browser. But when view on mobile the video won't load. To see if it's the .htaccess that cause the issue I remove the .htaccess, and it work fine after. My question is, is there a fix that will let me hotlink protection using .htaccess that would also work on mobile? Thanks in advance.

sorry, forgot to include.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(mp4|jpg|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: Could you post the .htaccess file that you're using? It's difficult to tell you how to fix it if we can't see it.

Comment: I've added the .htaccess sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an exclusion for mobile user-agents, you can go [here for the list](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html) of ones that you want to exclude. So what you'd end up with is something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# for android/ipad/iphone/BlackBerry/Nokia/Samsung/Windows Phone
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(Android|iPad|iPhone|BlackBerry|Nokia|SAMSUNG|Windows\ Phone)

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(mp4|jpg|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Keep in mind that referers and user agents can be completely spoofed, so this is not a fool-proof way or preventing resource leeching.

Comment: Nope that didn't work. Video not loading. And did you mean HTTP_USER_AGENT? I tried both.

Comment: @EvanCeasar Yeah, `HTTP_USER_AGENT`. You should [check your mobile device's user-agent](http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com/) to make sure you're including it in the pattern.

Comment: wait after reading it again, I don't want to exclude mobile from viewing the video. I just want it to work same as viewing on PC. For some reason the video won't load on mobile. I think it's the Safari browser not compatible.

Comment: @EvanCeasar The rule excludes whatever mobile user agents you add to the list so that **the rule won't get applied**. That means, you need to find your user-agent using the link in my previous comment, add that to the condition, so that the rule that results in a 403 *won't get applied to your user-agent*.

Comment: I think this work :), but is there a way to keep that hotlink protection for mobile also? Thanks.

Comment: @EvanCeasar The reason why your referer is different from a mobile browser is not fixable via htaccess, something else is causing the referer to be different (or maybe the referer is just blank?)

Comment: Adding Jon's RewriteCond line for mobile devices worked perfectly for me.